Rotax 912 ULS operates well on ground but poorly in air
I have a Rotax 912 ULS in a pusher configuration.
On the ground, run-up is good, the carburetors are balanced, both sides EGT are almost exactly the same, and there is no fouling on any plug.
However, immediately upon takeoff the engine starts running rough. I can see that the EGT on one side drops quite a bit. It feels like it's not running on all cylinders. Upon landing, the issue goes away.
I get the sense that there's some kind of issue which is being caused by the air pressure of being at a fast flying speed rather than a ground speed. The two things that come to mind are carburetors or possibly plug wires.  I've balanced the carbs, checked all the plugs, and done numerous ground run-ups. I suppose I could tighten all the plug wires into the boots. I'm running out of ideas.
The engine runs great on the ground. FYI, this is at a sea level airport with 22C weather. I'm staying in the pattern so I haven't gotten above 1000'.
Any ideas where to look?

What happens if you test your mags/lanes while it’s running poorly?

How is the air intake configured?  How fast do you fly?

That was my first thought too.  If airspeed is the variable it seems that disrupted flow might be in play...

To answer questions above: (1) mags test fine on ground, I'm not brave enough to test in the air!, (2) Air intake is via K&N filters which always have been good, (3) airspeed does seem to be a factor, but why I'm not sure.


forward facing K&N filters.


Is there any baffling or inlet that channels air to the filters?  Because if the filter element is forward facing maybe it's getting too much ram air and you need a supersonic intake ramp to slow it down?!  Conversely if the end of the filter faces forward and the element draws from the side, perhaps the intake flow gets turbulent at higher speed and chokes the engine?

Yes there are baffles. To be honest it has worked well before.

Air intake to fuel tank open enough?

"it has worked well before." Before what?  I.e. have you made any changes since the time it was running good?

In the winter. It sat for 6 months. I’ve replaced the fuel but I just discovered that the maximum octane in Canada is 94 not 91 as I thought. The station I bought fuel from only had 91 so I thought that was the max. I’m draining right now and trying with 94.

The answer appears to be (mostly) spark related, not air related as I originally thought.
After replacing one carb diaphragm and cleaning the light aluminum corrosion on that carb, I saw no change. Balancing the carbs showed no change. Carb floats were good although the bowls showed some residue from fuel which had evaporated; I cleaned this too. The rubber parts used to mount the carbs were also in good shape with no tears or cracks.
So that left spark. I noticed that my previous mechanic had used Denso IXU24 5309 iridium plugs which are not specified by Rotax. So I went to the auto parts store and got NGK DCPR8E 4339 plugs as specified (originally!) by Rotax. A quick change and that 99.99% solved the roughness problem.
Perhaps I'm focusing too much on it but that last 0.01% is the occasional - like once every few minutes - incredibly light feeling of roughness for about 1/10 of a second in flight. I'm going to chalk that up to being too hyper-sensitive to the engine for now unless there's something else I'm missing.

Thanks for posting the follow-up; this info may be useful for somebody else later with a similar issue.

Any analysis why the roughness only showed up in flight with the spark plug issue? Just curious if anything might explain that bservation.

I think it's possible that the spark plugs were the cause of ground roughness and the aluminum oxidation was the cause of the air roughness. My theory is that the aluminum oxidation created a tiny gap in the "cap" of one carb which had no effect on the ground, but as soon as there was airflow, it pushed the diaphragm down and correspondingly messed up the air/fuel mixture. But because doing that by itself didn't solve anything, I didn't fly it until I changed the plugs so I can't be 100% certain.

The ULS has an issue with their float balls getting fuel inside them. Have you checked your float balls to entire they are in good condition? This should be an uncommon issue but I see still see it quite often still.

If by float balls you mean the carb floats? I did actually replace them a few years ago based on the advisory that Rotax sent out. I suppose it's worth taking a look at them again, will do tomorrow.

One other thought that I had is, could it possibly be a carb diaphragm? It might perform fine on the ground but with air pressure from increased speed while flying (the air filters/intakes are pointed forward) maybe a small fault could cause erratic operation?

Ok so I replaced one of the carb diaphragms because it was in poor condition. The other was fine. I rebalanced the carbs too. Now it runs a lot better but still not perfectly. At least it feels safe to fly. But I still need to get it a bit smoother while flying.

Sorry for the late reply. Glad you got it to run better. What issues are you running into now?

I'm pretty sure the issue has to be spark plugs. My mechanic had been using Denso IXU24 5309 plugs but doing some research I've found that the correct plugs are NGK DCPR8E which is what Rotax shipped it with. I just ordered a set from the auto parts store and I'm going to give it a try.

How’s it running?

Still not perfectly. I am currently investigating whether I should change the setting of the carb pins. It was relocated from a high density altitude environment to a low density altitude environment. The Bing carbs have four positions on the pins, I haven't removed mine to check where they are. What makes me think of this is that the mag drop is 600 rpm on both mags during run-up which seems excessive. Thoughts?
